# Differences in shape of fields in Central Europe

Tags: landscaping

When checking satellite photos on Google Maps, I noticed that there's a striking visual difference between fields in some countries, namely Germany & Austria vs. Czech Republic & Slovakia. Take a look e.g. at [this part of the border](https://www.google.cz/maps/@49.3360997,12.9671541,13740m/data=!3m1!1e3); fields on the German part look much more divided into smaller segments.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: I think you should ask in history SE.  I learn some of such difference in history lessons, but for sure biased.  so I think in history SE you will have more answer (so less bias of your countries). The link: https://history.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on https://history.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Likely Soviet collective farm methods: Soviet Invasion of Czechoslovakia, 1968 https://history.state.gov/milestones/1961-1968/soviet-invasion-czechoslavkia Czechoslovakia was part of Soviet bloc after WWII.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about large-scale agriculture. Please see the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this in southern Austria/Burgenland is due to traditions surrounding inheritance, and is not related to farming methods. Landowners would divide their farm equally among their children rather than giving it to their oldest child. After many generations, the farms were carved down into the narrow strips you can see even today.

While farming methods didn't lead to the shape of the fields, the shape of the fields has determined what farming methods can be used today. They are impractical for large, modern farm machinery and in fact there has been consolidation of those fields in modern time so machinery can be used. If you look, you'll find discussions lamenting the change.

ETA: [This map](https://www.google.cz/maps/place/Burgenland,+Rakousko/@47.0435787,16.290189,7585m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x476c20c30e4adcf1:0x98424bb7b83ee8fa!8m2!3d47.1537165!4d16.2688797) shows clearly remnants of the old style fields (the narrow strips) and larger plots that have been consolidated in Burgenland. And [this map](https://www.google.cz/maps/place/Burgenland,+Rakousko/@47.0004909,16.1876358,3109m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x476c20c30e4adcf1:0x98424bb7b83ee8fa!8m2!3d47.1537165!4d16.2688797) is another area where the old style fields largely remain.